# MS Access - Problems using variables in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, variables, ms-access

I have a working query which takes too long to run. It is being used to populate an Access form field with a list of distinct contracts ordered by their start date.

The following query returns a list of distinct contract start dates for multiple commodities (which share contract start dates) where the contract start date (DELSTART) is greater or equal to the current date (PRICEDATE).

The function returndelivery returns a date attribute of the contract converted to a double, the function returnnumericdate just returns a double from a date (yyyymmdd).

```
SELECT DISTINCT (tblFuturesPrices.Period),
       returnnumericdate(returndelivery([PERIOD],"S")) AS DELSTART,
       ReturnNumericDate(Date()) AS PRICEDATE
FROM tblFuturesPrices
WHERE returnnumericdate(returndelivery([PERIOD],"S")) >= ReturnNumericDate(Date())
GROUP BY PERIOD
ORDER BY returnnumericdate(returndelivery([PERIOD],"S"));
```

Ideally I would like to refer to the variables DELSTART and PRICEDATE in the where clause but Access prompts for a variable value when I do so. I think the query takes longer than it should because I'm having to use my user defined functions numerous times.

The source table (tblFutures) contains prices for each commodity / contract for working days going back 6 months.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the optimizer smart enough to notice that the three repetitions of `returnnumericdate(returndelivery([PERIOD],"S"))` need only be evaluated once or would it help to push this into a derived table or `VIEW`?

Comment: I am thinking that I could populate a temp table which only updates when the form loads and the day has changed. I was hoping that the DELSTART declaration would hold the table values and referencing them later would be quicker.

Answer (score 0):

> I think the query takes longer than it should because I'm having to
>   use my user defined functions numerous times.

That's it. But you can reduce those functions:

```
returnnumericdate(returndelivery([PERIOD],"S")) >= ReturnNumericDate(Date())
```

will be no different from

```
returndelivery([PERIOD],"S") >= Date()
```

Don't know what *returndelivery* does.

**Addendum**:

Filter on the raw data and create a new function *returndeliverydate* that does the same as *returndelivery* except returns a Date value:

```
SELECT 
    tblFuturesPrices.Period,
    returndeliverydate([PERIOD],"S") AS DELSTART,
    Date() AS PRICEDATE
FROM 
    tblFuturesPrices
WHERE 
    returndeliverydate([PERIOD],"S") >= Date()
```

Save this query and use it as source in a new query:

```
Select Distinct
    DELSTART,
    PRICEDATE
FROM 
    YourQuery
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, returndelivery accepts a range of contract delivery names e.g. Nov16, Q1 17, Sum18 and returns the start date of the contract as a double. Access is so nasty with dates I gave up on it, So for example returndelivery('Nov16','S') would give you 20161101.

Comment: I see. But dates are not "nasty", neither something magic, just a subtype of Double. Using anything else than Date when dealing with date and time will only cause more trouble than doing it right. See addendum.

Comment: Thanks Gustav. I've nearly completed switching to a daily one of load of the strips in a temp table but will take a look at your suggestion regarding a new function.